# Build Native Image with GraalVM using jib

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, graalvm

I have a Spring Boot project with Maven and GraalVM which works fine and I am trying to create the containerized image for the same with GitLab CI with jib. I have added the jib plugin to the pom.xml file as shared below. I do not get any error if I do run `mvnw clean -Pnative native:compile` in Gitlab pipeline but running ./mvnw clean compile jib:build -Pnative -Dimage=$REPO:$TAG -Djib.container.environment=SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod gives the error

**ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build (default-cli) on project zoho: error running extension 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.extension.nativeimage.JibNativeImageExtension': Native-image executable does not exist or not a file: /builds/integrella/internal/zoho-integration/target/${start-class}
[ERROR] Did you run the 'native-image:native-image' goal?**

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>Application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.6.13</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
        <problem.version>0.26.0</problem.version>
        <org.json.version>20220320</org.json.version>
        <apache.commons.lang3.version>3.12.0</apache.commons.lang3.version>
        <checkstyle-plugin.version>3.2.0</checkstyle-plugin.version>
        <checkstyle.version>10.5.0</checkstyle.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${problem.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-problem</artifactId>
            <version>${problem.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <buildpacks>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/graalvm</buildpack>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
                        </buildpacks>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jib-native-image-extension-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <pluginExtensions>
                        <pluginExtension>
                            <implementation>com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.extension.nativeimage.JibNativeImageExtension</implementation>
                        </pluginExtension>
                    </pluginExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>checkstyle</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <excludes>**/module-info.java,**/target/**/*,**/protocols/**/*</excludes>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**GitLab File**

```
image: docker:20.10.8-dind-alpine3.13
services:
  - docker:20.10.8-dind

variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: "3"
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY: abc 
  CONTAINER_REPO: abc
  GCP_PROJECT_ID: abc
  CI_PROJECT_NAME: abc
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375


stages:
  - build

.container-build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17
    entrypoint: [""]
  tags:
    - gke
  before_script:
    - >-
      iso_to_unix_timestamp() {
        local DATEWITHOUT_TZ=$(echo $1 | sed 's/T/ /; s/[+-][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]//')
        local TZ_DIFF=$(echo $1 | grep -o "[+-][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print (a[1]<0 ? -1 : 1)*((a[1]<0 ? -1 : 1)*(3600*a[1] + (a[1]<0 ? -1 : 1)*60*a[2]))}')
        local TS_WITHOUT_TZ=$(date -d "${DATEWITHOUT_TZ}" +%s)
        echo $((TZ_DIFF + TS_WITHOUT_TZ))
      }
    - REPO=$CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$CONTAINER_REPO/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
    - TAG=main-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}-$(iso_to_unix_timestamp $CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP)

build-on-main:
  extends: .container-build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  script:
    - mvn compile jib:build -Dimage=$REPO:$TAG -Djib.container.environment=SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod

build-on-tag:
  extends: .container-build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  script:
    - TAG=${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
    - mvn compile jib:build -Dimage=$REPO:$TAG -Djib.container.environment=SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod

build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol9-java17-22.3.2
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    ./mvnw clean compile jib:build -Pnative -Dimage=myrepo:mytag -Djib.container.environment=SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
#    - ./mvnw clean -Pnative native:compile
```

Comment: (I have no experience with Gitlab, but) did you try running the goal it suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old topic but have you tried to add this property "imageName" ?

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-native-image-extension-maven#examples